# NSFetchedResultsController Not Caching correctly

Tags: ios, caching, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am having a weird issue. I have setup two NSFetchedResultsControllers

Like so

```
// Setup Fetched Results Controller
[self setFilesController:[PCSDataAccessor filesInDirectroy:@"" forWorkgroup:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] withContext:[PCSManagedObjectContext context]]];
[self setWorkgroupsController:[PCSDataAccessor memberWorkgroupsFetchedResultsControllerWithContext:[PCSManagedObjectContext context]]];

#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller Methods

+ (NSFetchedResultsController *)memberWorkgroupsFetchedResultsControllerWithContext:(PCSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    // Create Fetch Request
    NSEntityDescription * entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PCSManagedWorkgroup" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    // Set workgroupID to find
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(workgroupID != 0)"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    // Set Sort Options
    NSSortDescriptor * sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    // Create Feched Results Controller
    NSFetchedResultsController * resultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"workgroups"];

    // Return Results
    return resultsController;
}

+ (NSFetchedResultsController *)filesInDirectroy:(NSString *)directoryPath forWorkgroup:(NSNumber *)workgroupID withContext:(PCSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    // Create Fetch Request
    NSEntityDescription * entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PCSManagedFile" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    // Set File to find
    NSString * regexString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"^%@[^/]+$",directoryPath];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"workgroup.workgroupID == %@ && name matches %@",workgroupID,regexString];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    // Set Sort Options
    NSSortDescriptor * sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    // Create Feched Results Controller
    NSFetchedResultsController * resultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",workgroupID,directoryPath]];

    // Return Results
    return resultsController;
}
```

When I add things to core data that would return in the request they show up like you would expect. The only issue that I am having is when I terminate the app and bring it back up both fetched requests controllers say they have no data. I can query core data and they are there.

I have been able to solve this problem by passing in nil for the cache name.

I would like to be able to use a cache since i will have multiple fetched results controllers and they could have large data sets in them.

Comment: Do you have a `performFetch:` somewhere?

Comment: Yes I have only one view controller right now and I call it in the viewWillAppear method

Comment: In which case, I can't see why your problem should be occurring.  But I notice that both FRCs have sectionNameKeyPath set to nil, so I'm not sure that the cache will be doing much.